# Github - transfer issues between two private repos

Tags: git, github, issue-tracking

Let's say **user A** owns a private **repo A** on Github.
He is part of an organization which has a private **repo B**.
**User A** has admin privileges on both **repo A** & **repo B**.

**User A** wants to transfer an issue from his own **repo A** to his organization's **repo B**.

He can't do that since the **repo B** doesn't appear in the choices of repo to transfer to.

Why? Since he's an admin, he should be able to.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting the corresponding section on Github:

> To transfer an open issue to another repository, you must have admin permissions on the repository the issue is in and the repository you're transferring the issue to. If you're transferring an issue from a repository that's owned by an organization you're a member of, you must transfer it to another repository within your organization. For more information, see "Repository permission levels for an organization."

[Here](https://help.github.com/articles/transferring-an-issue-to-another-repository/) is the link to follow for more complete details.

Comment: I'm not transferring an issue from a repository that's owned by an organisation. I'm transferring an issue **TO** a repository that's owned by an organisation

Comment: From the above it shouldn't matter, issues can be transferred among repos **within** the organization.